# as good ~ as I ever knew

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, as

> “Now, yer mum an' dad were **as good a witch an' wizard as I ever knew**.”
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What’s the meaning of the highlighted part?

Comment: From here (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harry's mum was a good witch and his dad was a good wizard.

> **Yer mum and dad were a good witch an’ wizard.**

How good were they? They were as good as any witch or wizard I ever knew.

> Yer mum and dad were **as good** a witch an’ wizard **as I ever knew**.

These constructions are *maybe, possibly, just a little bit* too colloquial for, say, an exceptionally dry academic journal; but anywhere else they’re fine.

Comment: So the sentence itself has no meaning of “they were the best or ones of the best wizards Hagrid had met, but “they were really as good as any wizards he’d known in those days” hasn’t it?

Comment: @Listenever  Ah, that's a bit different question. I think most people would take that *ever* to extend Hagrid's reference up to the 'present' in which Hagrid is speaking; it's almost a fixed phrase which sits outside the ordinary narrative reference. But you're right that he does not make that explicit, as he would by saying *as I've ever known*. I don't think Hagrid is that careful a speaker!

Comment: @StoneyB: If Hagrid was a *careful* speaker, I think he might be more likely to have said *"...as good a witch an’ wizard as ever I knew"* (purely on the grounds of stylistic elegance, not grammar as such! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yah, me too; I kept typing it as that.

Comment: @StoneyB, Does this sentence have the same meanng: “Yer mum an' dad were as good as the witch an' wizards I ever knew.”? Or is it meaning just as “Yer mum and dad were as good a witch an’ wizard as I ever knew,” literally? : so they were good as much as I had known them?

Comment: @Listenever Let me pseudo-mathematicalize: mum and dad were members of the set {witches and wizards}. Hagrid compares mum and dad to every other [member of that set] whom he ever knew, and concludes that mum and dad were as good as any such [other member] (and, presumably, better than some).

Comment: @StoneyB, Yes, now, I start to get your sayings. And pardon me a further question: “He is as great a scientist as ever lived.” means “ He is as great as any scientist ever lived”? or is he the best?

Comment: @Listenever “He is as great a scientist as **any that** ever lived.” would mean he is just as great as any scientist that ever lived, and (to steal StoneyB's phrasing!) presumably better than some of them.

Comment: @Listenever As WendiKidd says, he's right up there with Newton and Einstein. He's not greater than those, but they're not greater than he is, either.

Answer (score 3):

They have used superlative degree.

We use superlative degree when we compare more than two persons or things with one another.

It means that (Harry's) Mom and Dad were the best witch and wizard the person had ever know.

Comment: Deepika you're right.

Comment: Not quite. It means not that they were better than all others but that no others were better than they: they were *among* the best, they were as good as the best.