# omission in comparative clauses

Tags: comparative

> "Now, yer mum an' dad were as good a witch an' wizard as **I ever
>   knew**."
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

This comparative construction, I suppose, has the omission of “counterpart of comparative phrase normally omitted ([CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/),p.1108)”. From [Wendikidd’s comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/as-good-as-i-ever-knew), the complement of *as* before omission would be ‘*any of those* I ever knew’ or ‘*those* I ever knew’ (*those*: good witches and wizards). Are both accepted or one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W e l l . . . You may certainly, with grammatical propriety, *paraphrase* this as

> ***as good as***
>     any ∅
>     any whom
>     any that
>     any of those ∅
>     any of those whom
>     any of those that
>     those ∅
>     those whom
>     those that
>     all others ∅
>     all others whom
>     all others that               ***I ever knew***

But with all respect to Profs. Pullum and Huddleston, that range of choices makes it difficult to say that anything in particular is *omitted*, except in the Pickwickian sense that they’re *all* omitted. You can't “omit” something that was never there to begin with.

It may make Pulludelum's job easier, and their model more parsimonious, to *pretend* that something is omitted; but the fact is, they're importing that something ***into*** the sentence.

Comment: Then yours explanation maybe similar with a Koran English Grammar book, in that it condiders no omission. It says ‘as’ in the structure is a kind of similar relative. So they insist that ‘as’ is the object of ‘knew’ and at the same time ‘as’ is connective adjunct that leads a subordinate clause.

Comment: @Listenever Yes; I'm not sure I'd put it that way, but it's closer to my way of thinking than CGEL's. Transformationalists seem to me just a bit too ready to stretch the language to fit the way they think.

Comment: @StoneyB Unlike McCawley, H&P explicitly reject *transformations*. They talk instead about *processes*, which are (to them) a convenient method of simplifying their descriptions.  But they caution their readers that all of the "process" descriptions can be rewritten in purely static terms (though it would make for a much longer book!).  In other words, they don't believe in "underlying" forms of sentences; they talk about subject-auxiliary inversion, but they don't *really* believe that we start with declarative sentences and reorder the words every time we form a question.  And so on.

Comment: @snailboat Point well taken. I tend through laziness to label (libel?) as transformationalist everything that's happened since I was in high school. And I have to confess that all I've know about CGEL is Huddleston's précis. In some respects they seem to be actually a lot more traditionalist than even me.