# the prettiest girl I've ever met

Tags: comparison

> “You’re still the prettiest girl **I’ve ever met**.”
>  (Ken
>   Follett, Fall of Giants)

I guess the clause give a range for picking up one out of it. Does the clause give a meaning of basket out of which the speaker can pick one?

Comment: Could you try restating your question, I am not able to parse it as written.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer is the same as to [your previous question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10902/omission-in-comparative-clauses). If someone is the best/smartest/prettiest person/wizard you've ever met/known, it means that of all the people/wizards you've ever met/known in your entire life, this person is the most good/smart/pretty.

Comment: Re: your edit: Not really... It's already been qualified by saying *you* are *the prettiest girl*. There's no one to pick from, because before the speaker says "I've ever met" they've already chosen the girl and defined her as the prettiest. *You are the prettiest girl in the room* means "Of every girl in this room, you are the prettiest." *You are the prettiest girl I've ever met* means "Of every girl I've ever met, you are the prettiest." It's just like your other question; it's not any more complex than that. Does that make sense? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically, I think you're right:

> You’re the prettiest girl.

This means that, out of some *unspecified set of girls*, the listener is the prettiest.  (The set is determined by context; it could be *all girls*, or it could be a much smaller set.)

But you can specify the set:

> You're the prettiest girl **in the whole world**.

Now the set is *all the girls on Earth*.  Of that set, she is the prettiest.  This is quite a compliment!

Of course, the set can be much smaller:

> You're the prettiest girl **in the room**.

Now the set is *all the girls in the room*.  Of that set, she is the prettiest.

(Of course, if she's the **only** girl in the room, that might not be a compliment!  In that case, the sentence would be a type of insult called [*damning with faint praise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damning_with_faint_praise).)

Now, let's look at your sentence:

> You're the prettiest girl **I've ever met**.

The set is *all the girls the speaker has ever met*.  Of that set, the listener is the prettiest.

Comment: I understand well. Whenever I read the construction, I unwittingly insert "of that" in the sentence, yet there's none of it in fact. That's why I'm confused. Thank you very much